# emulate Ie7 on ie6

Tags: asp.net

is it possible to  emulate Ie7 on ie6  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't.
However, there are various compatibility toolkits:

- http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/
- http://www.google.com/chromeframe

Answer (score 2):

Short answer no.

For a longer answer it would be helpful to give more information about what you are trying to achieve.